# Comparar elementos de listas desordenadas JAVA

Tags: java, lista

Tengo dos objetos estado (`e1` y `e2`) en Java. Estos cuentan con una lista de objetos llaves como atributo que tienen una posición X y una Y con sus respectivos `llave.getX()`, `llave.getY()`. Quiero comprobar que estos atributos de `e1` y `e2` tienen llaves en las mismas posiciones o no, pero al estar en distinto orden no puedo hacer una simple comparación.

`if (i.getX()==j.getX() && i.getY()==j.getY()) { ... }` dentro de:

```
for (Llave i : e1.llavesE) {
    for (Llave j : e2.llavesE) {
        /// COMPROBAR
    }    
}
```

Con este algoritmo:

```
boolean llaveaux = true;
for (Llave i : e1.llavesE) {
    if (llaveaux) {
        llaveaux = false;
        for (Llave j : e2.llavesE) {
            if (i.getX()==j.getX() && i.getY()==j.getY()) {
                llaveaux = true;
                break;
            }
        } 
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}

return true;
```

Creía que se solucionaria mi problema, pero no. ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo resolver esto? y ¿por qué no funciona mi segunda idea?

Un saludo y muchas gracias :)

Comment: Cual es el sentido del if? cual es la logica de tu proceso? que es lo que estas buscando exactamente? tu codigo es confuso, y la logica tambien.

Comment: Si el orden es importante porque usas una lista desordenada?

Comment: el primer if funcionaría para comprobar si ambas listas tienen las llaves en las mismas posiciones si y solo si, las listas estuvieran ordenadas de igual manera. Pero como este no es el caso, mi idea es ir llave por llave dentro de la lista de e1 comprobando si esta en e2. En el momento en que encuentre una coincidencia, pasará a la siguiente llave. Si en algún momento ha recorrido toda la lista de llaves de e2 y no ha encontrado coincidencia alguna, significará que las listan son distintas. Pero hay algo que se me escapa. @gbianchi

Comment: @Juan el resto del programa por complejidad fuerza a que en algún momento las listas introduzcan llaves o las borren de forma que se desordenen y considero mas fácil buscar una solución al problema de la comparación antes q al de ordenar las listas :/

Answer (score 0):

Voy a suponer que `e1.llavesE` y `e2.llavesE` devuelven un arrayList de `llave`.

Si los objetos que están en una lista son los mismos que hay en la otra (mismo objeto) se puede usar los `idexOf()` para ver que posiciones ocupan en la listas. También lo que tenias puesto de llaveaux es innecesario.

```
for (Llave i : e1.llavesE) {
   if(!e2.llavesE.contains(i) || e1.llavesE.indexOf(i)!=e2.llavesE.indexOf(i)
   {             
          return false;           
   }      
}
return true;
```

Si los objetos Llaves no son iguales en ambas listas, pero son fácilmente comparables como pones en tu ejemplo, que se pueden comparar con un `i.getX()==j.getX() && i.getY()==j.getY()`, entonces optaria por antes sobrescribir el metodo equals de la clase Llave [Sobbrescribir equals](https://dev.to/havarem/override-equals-method-in-java-2b3j)

```
public class Llave{
  private int x;
  private int y;

  //......Implementacion de codigo

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if(obj instanceOf Llave)
     {
        Llave otherKey=(Llave)obj;
        if(obj.getX() == x && obj.getY()== y)
        {
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

Si no sobrescribes el equals, nunca los va a detectar como iguales, ya que los objetos, internamente tienen mas atributos de los que especificas en tu implementación. Al sobrescribir el equals, forzamos a que solo compruebe la similitud con los atributos que nosotros especifiquemos.